# How to avoid long list of arguments to a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, arguments

I have a stored procedure to update certain values in two tables. But the list of arguments or the set of values to update has grown to 10 arguments and could grow more in future. How could this be handled?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_base_plan`(userId int,newPlanId int,nextPlanId int,maxCreditPulseAllocated int)
begin
        if userId is not null and newPlanId is not null and nextPlanId is not null 
                                               and maxCreditPulseAllocated is not null
              then
                update planallocation as pa
                left join subscriptioninfo as si 
                on pa.SubscriptionId = si.SubscriptionId
                left join plans as pl
                on pa.CurrentPlanId = pl.PlanId
                set pa.CurrentPlanId = newPlanId, pa.NextPlanId = nextPlanId,
                pa.MaxCreditPulseAllocated = maxCreditPulseAllocated
                where pl.Plan_Type = 'base' and 
                si.UserId = userId;
        end if;
    end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well technically, when a (stored) procedure requires *n* parameters, you're usually not getting around providing *n* parameters.

In some programming languages however, instead of providing all those parameters one at a time, an array / dictionary / object is provided, turning into "one parameter". I'm not certain, if this is possible in mysql, but you probably can use json as input and make mysql unpack it (or however you'd call it). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html for example (and sibling pages).

Depending on the datatypes you could do other encodings similar to csv or new line separated. However, I'd advise against positional arguments, when they aren't communicated well enough.

Comment: Does MySQL have support for JSON?

Comment: in newer versions yes. Don't know which version introduced it though. quick look at the page suggests only version 5.7 has the json functions ... sad ;o/